# Order a Firebase database and then iterate through and update an item with Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question regarding Firebase. It's about to set up a leaderboard database.
So my question is: Is it possible to first order a database by a child "score", then iterate through this specific order and simultaneously update the child "ranking" in the database?

Here's the scheme of the database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5twJH.png

Can't find any solution so far. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your firebase database scheme?

Comment: @DionizB: I added a screenshot from the scheme

Comment: Are you asking how to do this, or if this will work or not?

Comment: @DionizB: I'm asking, if this is possible to do or not. And if it's possible, I would be thankful about some hints/code samples, because I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to declare your database reference:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Leaderboard")
```

Then you need to do a simple query here and access elements on the query:

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Score").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for (index, child) in snapshot.children.enumerated {
        if let leaderboardSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot, let leaderBoardValues = leaderboardSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]  { 
            // here you should update your children
            let values = ["Name": (leaderBoardValues["Name"] as? String) ?? " ", "Ranking": index, "Score":  (leaderBoardValues["Score"] as? Int) ?? 0] 
            ref.child(leaderboardSnapshot.key).updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                        // check for error here if you want
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good approach. I had to rename FIRDataSnapshot to DataSnapshot and leaderboardDictionary.key to leaderboardDictionary.keys to stop Xcode crying. But I still have some Issues with the Dictionaries???
https://i.imgur.com/tcuYnK9.png

Comment: With your new code, I get this result: https://i.imgur.com/d69L28d.png. But my goal is, that the database looks like this at the end: https://i.imgur.com/pcgLvUx.png. And there is still the problem with the counter for the ranking, that it's not getting up with every hit.

Comment: Use the edited answer, I updated the code to fulfill your needs

Comment: Unfortunately the new code writes nothing to the database :(

Comment: Can you make any prints or debug to see why it doesn't write anything? Because theoretically it should update your rank value

Comment: I wrote a print method into the is statements, to check if the code is even entering the if statements, and nothing was printed t the console. https://i.imgur.com/Z9NvlNT.png. So seems that the code is not running the if statements.

Comment: Can you try again now?

Comment: It works, you are a genius! Thank you a thousand times. You made my day!!!

Comment: @DaliborSimic haha happy to help :D